# What should I be looking for in a gas cap?

Tags: fuel-cap

I've misplaced my fuel cap because reasons.  I need to get a new one, but I'm not sure what exactly I should be looking for or how to figure out what will work for my vehicle.

Are all caps the same?  Are gas caps universal enough that buying one would work for most any car?  If not, what would be the best way to determine if a given cap would work for my vehicle?

I specifically have a 2008 Pontiac G6, but hopefully this question could be applied to any person in a similar predicament.

Comment: If you have a local auto scrap yard, give them a call to see if they have your car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the price difference is outrageous, you're probably better off sticking with OEM. The reason being is that aftermarket caps (even by reputable brands) can leak, and based on what I remember hearing on Car Talk, it's not unusual. Leaking is bad because your emissions system can't work properly and you'll end up getting a check engine light. The other advantage is aftermarkets don't seem to include the straps and what-have-you that tether the cap to the car. That said, I've used Gates on a few cars and had no problems.

I agree with MooseLucifer, too. If you have one nearby, getting one from a local scrap yard (or eBay) would be a very cheap option. There's a *really* good chance your cap will fit other cars, so having a list of those other cars would make the scrap yard trip easier. Maybe someone else can pipe in with how to get said list.

Comment: +1: one of the most common reasons for check engine light is a loose or leaky gas cap. I would too prefer OEM.

Answer (score 2):

The gas cap you are looking at *is* a fairly generic gas cap.  However, not just any one will fit on.  If you get a gas cap from one of the following vehicles, [it should fit](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/NEW-Genuine-Authentic-GM-ACDelco-Factory-OEM-Fuel-Tank-System-Filler-Gas-Cap-/131891835855?fits=Year%3A2008%7CMake%3APontiac%7CModel%3AG6&hash=item1eb55db3cf:g:5ZsAAOSwofxUbhuq&vxp=mtr):

- 2006-2012 Chevrolet Impala
- 2005-2012 Chevrolet Malibu
- 2005-2010 Chevrolet Cobalt
- 2006-2010 Chevrolet HHR
- 2007-2010 Pontiac G5
- 2005-2010 Pontiac G6
- 2006-2009 Buick Allure
- 2006-2009 Buick LaCrosse
- 2005-2009 Chevrolet Aveo
- 2005-2009 Chevrolet Equinox
- 2009 Pontiac G3
- 2006-2009 Pontiac Solstice
- 2006-2009 Pontiac Torrent
- 2007-2009 Saturn Aura
- 2007-2009 Saturn Sky
- 2005-2008 Pontiac Grand Prix
- 2006 Buick Rendezvous
- 2006-2007 Chevrolet Monte Carlo
- 2006-2007 Saturn Ion
- 2005-2006 Pontiac Pursuit

Check to make sure that the particular trim matches your vehicle's as well...

Comment: Most of the auto stores in my area provide a way to lookup parts (like headlights) by make/model.  I'm more interested in how I would go about getting a list like the one you've provided.

Comment: Sorry, don't actually know where you can get lists like that one.  I compiled that one manually.  :)

Comment: A scrap yard is likely to be able to tell you at least some of the compatible vehicles.